# Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()

Tags: php, laravel, function, arguments

I have the following error.

> Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()

```
public function upteamLogs(Request $request)
{
    $logs = DB::table('upteam_product_logs');

    if ($request->from_date != '' && $request->to_date != '') {
        $logs->whereBetween('created_at', 
            array($request->from_date, $request->to_date));
    }

    $logs->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(30)->get();
    
    return view("product-inventory.upteam_logs", compact('logs'));
}
```

Comment: after paginate get will not working

Comment: no need to use get after paginate, just remove it

Answer (score 0):

the method `paginate` and `simplePaginate` of the laravel `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` class return respectively and instance classes which have implemented [`Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html) or [`Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\Paginator`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Pagination/Paginator.html) interface and those interfaces havent define `get` method that's main reason of the error.

You should just return the reassign the result of the `paginate` call directly to the `$log` variable like this

```
$logs = $logs->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(30);
```

This will fix your error and you can loop through logs into your `product-inventory.upteam_logs` view without any problem